# Do the Charge Badges in Streetpass Mansion stack?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-mansion-monster-manor

I have a charge badge (plus 5% to charge speed) and charge badge +1 (plus 10% to charge speed) in my inventory in the StreetPass Mansion game.

Do these bonuses stack to give 15% or do I only have 10%?